# Infinitely many primes

Tags: code-golf, sequence, integer, primes, factoring

Since Euclid, we have known that there are infinitely many primes. The argument is by contradiction: If there are only finitely many, let's say \$p_1,p_2,...,p_n\$, then surely \$m:=p_1\cdot p_2\cdot...\cdot p_n+1\$ is not divisible by any of these primes, so its prime factorization must yield a new prime that was not in the list. So the assumption that only finitely primes exist is false.

Now let's assume that \$2\$ is the only prime. The method from above yields \$2+1=3\$ as a new (possible) prime. Applying the method again yields \$2\cdot 3+1=7\$, and then \$2\cdot 3\cdot 7+1=43\$, then \$2\cdot 3\cdot 7\cdot 43+1=13\cdot 139\$, so both \$13\$ and \$139\$ are new primes, etc. In the case where we get a composite number, we just take the least new prime. This results in [A000945](http://oeis.org/A000945).

#### Challenge

Given a prime \$p_1\$ and an integer \$n\$ calculate the \$n\$-th term \$p_n\$ of the sequence defined as follows:

$$p_n := \min(\operatorname{primefactors}(p_1\cdot p_2\cdot ... \cdot p_{n-1} + 1))$$

These sequences are known as *Euclid-Mullin*-sequences.

#### Examples

For \$p_1 = 2\$:

```
1 2
2 3
3 7
4 43
5 13
6 53
7 5
8 6221671
9 38709183810571
```

For \$p_1 = 5\$ ([A051308](http://oeis.org/A051308)):

```
1 5
2 2
3 11
4 3
5 331
6 19
7 199
8 53
9 21888927391
```

For \$p_1 = 97\$  ([A051330](http://oeis.org/A051330))

```
1 97
2 2
3 3
4 11
5 19
6 7
7 461
8 719
9 5
```

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>45</s>  44 bytes

Takes input as `(n)(p1)`, where \$n\$ is 0-indexed.

```javascript
n=>g=(p,d=2)=>n?~p%d?g(p,d+1):--n?g(p*d):d:p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxRC4IwFEbf@xX3wWA3p5RQkTZ96ldE4HBqC9kuGr2M9dfXfOvp4xwO30t@5NLNmt6ZsaoPgwhG1KNgxJUoUNSm@dJWNeMq0gOWWWZW2CksVUmhuhccjhwu50c@2PkmuycjEDW4DUAUTIOAfQUarnCKk6YInTWLnfp8siNrJUsceZ447TGmiRuYRkboW6zixX8bhcfwAw)

#### Commented

```javascript
n =>                // n = 0-based index of the requested term
  g = (             // g is a recursive function taking:
    p,              //   p = current prime product
    d = 2           //   d = current divisor
  ) =>              //
    n ?             // if n is not equal to 0:
      ~p % d ?      //   if d is not a divisor of ~p (i.e. not a divisor of p + 1):
        g(p, d + 1) //     increment d until it is
      :             //   else:
        --n ?       //     decrement n; if it's still not equal to 0:
          g(p * d)  //       do a recursive call with the updated prime product
        :           //     else:
          d         //       stop recursion and return d
    :               // else:
      p             //   don't do any recursion and return p right away
```

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

This produces and infinite output stream.

```
λλP>fW
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3O5Di8/tDrBLC///34jLDAA) (link includes a slightly modified version, `λ£λP>fW`, which instead outputs the first \$n\$ terms)

#### Explanation

Very straightforward. Given \$p_1\$ and \$n\$, the program does the following:

- Starts with \$p_1\$ as an initial parameter for the infinite stream (which is generated using the first `λ`) and begins a *recursive environment* which generates a new term after each interation and appends it to the stream.
- The second `λ`, now being used *inside* the recursive environment, changes its functionality: Now, it retrieves all previously generated elements (i.e. the list \$[\lambda_0, \lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_{n-1}]\$), where \$n\$ represents the current iteration number.
- The rest is trivial: `P` takes the product (\$\lambda_0\lambda_1\lambda_2 \cdots \lambda_{n-1}\$), `>` adds one to this product, and `fW` retrieves the minimum prime factor.

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 15 bytes

-10 bytes thanks to miles!

Returning the sequence up to n (zero-indexed) – thanks to [@miles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/6710/miles)

```
(,0({q:)1+*/)^:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NXQMNKoLrTQNtbX0NeOs/mtyKXClJmfkK1gopCkYQZiWQKYpQtTS/D8A)

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 25 bytes

Returns the `n` th item

```
_2{((],0{[:q:1+*/@])^:[])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/442qNTRidQyqo60KrQy1tfQdYjXjrKJjNf9rcilwpSZn5CtYKKQpGEGYlkCmKULU0vw/AA)

Comment: `(,0({q:)1+*/)^:` for 15 bytes, returning the sequence up to `n` (zero-indexed)

Comment: Very nice.  @miles what exactly is happening there grammatically? we put a verb and a conjunction together and get a dyadic verb back.  I thought `verb conj` [produced an adverb](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dictf.htm).

Comment: @Jonah it's a trick I learned from golfing. I think it's one of the older parsing rules that's still valid

Comment: @miles I just realized it is an adverb (or adnoun).  It modifies the noun to its left, which "attaches" to the right of the `^:`, and then _that_ becomes a verb that applies to the right arg.  I think that's what's happening grammatically.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

```python
i=input();k=1
while 1:
 k*=i;print i;i=2
 while~k%i:i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9M2M6@gtERD0zrb1pCrPCMzJ1XB0IpLIVvLNtO6oCgzr0Qh0zrT1ohLASxXl62aaZWpbWv4/7@lOQA)

---

### Commented

```python
i=input() # the initial prime
k=1       # the product of all previous primes
while 1:  # infinite loop
 k*=i     # update the product of primes
 print i  # output the last prime
 i=2      # starting at two ...
 while~k%i: # find the lowest number that divides k+1
  i+=1
            # this our new prime
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/RagMhEEXf/YoLJdA2sLB5CQ34MTaa7rDGER2z9CW/vtG4pZB5GRjPXM/EX5k4HNaVNIVY5P0Db5DJgQIJGY@Y6OrUrEf06q8xsS1nAV9gfIPcjbjkTme1TOQdxlPDKVxaloNnjgrzp6YtqERr6vwlb4toPQiogVykqj1Bb7JsTiB9@HPKYpJQ@IGp2MIYhkHhaXGfd3SqRJWwPYEXVzNCuX67VCd1w9KNrMuY96MCaK9b@692MuVqkRDc0n9f16/jAw)

Comment: I just started with Python, but do you need `int(input())` otherwise `i` is a `str`?

Comment: In Python 3 this would be true as `input()` always returns strings. In Python 2 `input()` tries to evaluate the input. I'm using Python 2 in this case because the resulting code is slightly shorter. For *real* code you should try to use Python 3 as it is the newer and more supported version of Python.

Comment: How does this terminate after n steps?

Comment: @sintax it outputs the sequence for a given p1 indefinitely, as allowed by the [default sequence rules](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info).

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
P‘ÆfṂṭµ¡
```

A full program (using zero indexing) accepting \$P_0\$ and \$n\$ which prints a Jelly representation of the list of \$P_0\$ to \$P_n\$ inclusive. (As a dyadic Link, with `n=0` we'll be given back an integer, not a list.)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9qZWxsef//UOKAmMOGZuG5guG5rcK1wqH///81/zg)**

#### How?

```
P‘ÆfṂṭµ¡ - Link: integer, p0; integer n
      µ¡ - repeat the monadic chain to the left n times, starting with x=p0:
P        -   product of x (p0->p0 or [p0,...,pm]->pm*...*p0)
 ‘       -   increment
  Æf     -   prime factors
    Ṃ    -   minimum
     ṭ   -   tack
         - implicit print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
GDˆ¯P>fß
```

First input is \$n\$, second is prime \$p\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f3eV026H1AXZph@f//2/GZQoA) or [very some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9m4Vppr6SQmJeioGTvB2Q9apsEZFX6/Xd3Od12aH2AXdrh@f9rdQ5t@R9tpGOqY2keCwA) (test suite lacks the test cases for \$n\geq9\$, because for \$p=2\$ and \$p=5\$ the builtin `f` takes too long).

**Explanation:**

```python
G         # Loop (implicit input) n-1 amount of times:
 Dˆ       #  Add a copy of the number at the top of the stack to the global array
          #  (which will take the second input p implicitly the first iteration)
   ¯      #  Push the entire global array
    P     #  Take the product of this list
     >    #  Increase it by 1
      f   #  Get the prime factors of this number (without counting duplicates)
       ß  #  Pop and only leave the smallest prime factor
          # (after the loop: implicitly output the top of the stack as result)
```

Comment: I had `λλP>fW` (6 bytes) with output as an infinite list and `λ£λP>fW` (7 bytes) for the first \$n\$ terms. However getting the \$n^{\text{th}}\$ should be 9 bytes... If only we had a flag like `£` but for the last element!

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder "_If only we had a flag like `£` but for the last element!_", like `.£`? ;) EDIT: Actually, it doesn't work exactly like `£` for lists.. using a list like `[1,2]` with `.£` results in two loose items with the last 1 and 2 items (i.e. `12345` becomes `[5,45]` instead of `[45,3]` or `[3,45]`, with `12S.£`)..

Comment: Umm, no, I don't see how `λ.£` should work. I used *flag* as in additional function associated with `λ` (see [this conversation with Adnan](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46253566#46253566)). I basically want some flag `è` such that when running `λè...}` it would generate the n-th element rather than the the infinite stream (just like `λ£` would work for generating the first n elements).

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Ah sorry, you've used the `£` for the recursive environment. Yeah, then `λ.£` is indeed not gonna work, my bad. Nice 6-byter regardless. Now you just have to wait for _@flawr_'s response whether it's allowed or not (it probably is).

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>12</s> 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Struggled to get this one right so may have missed something that can be golfed.

Takes `n` as the first input and `p1`, as a singleton array, as the second. Returns the first `n` terms. Change `h` to `g` to return the `n`th 0-indexed term instead.

```
@Z×Ä k Î}hV
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QFrXxCBrIM59aFY&input=OQpbOTdd)

```
@Z×Ä k Î}hV     :Implicit input of integer U=n & array V=[p1]
@               :Function taking an array as an argument via parameter Z
 Z×             :  Reduce Z by multiplication
   Ä            :  Add 1
     k          :  Prime factors
       Î        :  First element
        }       :End function
         hV     :Run that function, passing V as Z, and
                : push the result to V.
                : Repeat until V is of length U
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 56 bytes

```
,|$
$*
"$&"{~`.+¶
$$¶_
)`\b(__+?)\1*$
$.1$*
1A`
.$

\*
,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X6dGhUtFi0tJRU2pui5BT/vQNi4VlUPb4rk0E2KSNOLjte01Ywy1gGr0DIHKDB0TuPRUuLhitLh0/v835TLSMQYA) Takes input as the number of new terms to add on the first line and the seed term(s) on the second line. Note: Gets very slow since it uses unary factorisation so it needs to create a string of the relevant length. Explanation:

```
,|$
$*
```

Replace the commas in the seed terms with `*`s and append a `*`. This creates a Retina expression for a string of length of the product of the values.

```
"$&"{
)`
```

Repeat the loop the number of times given by the first input.

```
~`.+¶
$$¶_
```

Temporarily replace the number on the first line with a `$` and prepend a `_` to the second line, then evaluate the result as a Retina program, thus appending a string of `_`s of length 1 more than the product of the values.

```
\b(__+?)\1*$
$.1$*
```

Find the smallest nontrivial factor of the number in decimal and append a `*` ready for the next loop.

```
1A`
```

Delete the iteration input.

```
.$
```

Delete the last `*`.

```
\*
,
```

Replace the remaining `*`s with `,`s.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 54 bytes

```javascript
f=(p,n,P=p,F=n=>-~P%n?F(n+1):n)=>--n?f(p=F(2),n,P*p):p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fc1BC4JAEIbhe79iDgYzuQYKUWmTN8/eI1DMjUJmB40uYn99c08fPHzwvttvO3XjSz@JuEfvvWVUI6ZmNRULX5NfvZWyQolTyoVWSKS0qFxhRuG4U8rVWzeigrNwy8zBnI932gAEFE4LuZwKieNAAJ2TyQ39fnBPbCxGsy4GolkWAl7XhjwtDRX@Dw)

**Ungolfed**

```javascript
F=(p,n=2)=>            // Helper function F for finding the smallest prime factor
  p%n                  //   If n (starting at 2) doesn't divide p:
    ?F(n+1)            //     Test n+1 instead
    :n                 //   Otherwise, return n
f=(p,n,P=p)=>          // Main function f:
  --n                  //   Repeat n - 1 times:
    ?f(p=F(P+1),n,P*p) //     Find the next prime factor and update the product
    :p                 //   Return the last prime
```

Answer (score 2):

## bash +GNU coreutils, 89 bytes

```
IFS=\*;n=$1;shift;for((;++i<n;));{ set $@ `factor $["$*+1"]|cut -d\  -f2`;};echo ${@: -1}
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/39Mt2DZGyzrPVsXQujgjM63EOi2/SEPDWls70ybPWlPTulqhOLVEQcVBISEtMbkkv0hBJVpJRUvbUCm2Jrm0REE3JUZBQTfNKMG61jo1OSNfQaXawUpB17D2////5v9NAQ)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby 2.6, 51 bytes

```
f=->s,n{[s,l=(2..).find{|d|~s%d<1}][n]||f[l*s,n-1]}
```

`(2..)`, the infinite range starting from 2, isn't supported on TIO yet.

This is a recursive function that takes a starting value `s` (can be a prime or composite), returns it when n=0 (edit: note that this means it's zero-indexed), returns the least number `l` that's greater than 1 and divides `-(s+1)` when n=1, and otherwise recurses with `s=l*s` and `n=n-1`.

Comment: You should probably mention that you're doing zero-indexed; I replaced `(2..)` with `2.step` (just 1 byte longer) to allow it to work on TIO and everything was off by one. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W165YJ686ulgnx9ZIr7gktUAvLTMvpbompaauWDXFxrA2NjovtqYmLTpHC6hQ1zC29n9BaUmxgoaBnp65pl5uYkF1TWaNgpJydWatgnJ1WrSRTmZsrVLtfwA "Ruby – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 15 bytes

This is a fairly simple implementation of the algorithm which uses Extended's very helpful prime factors builtin, `⍭`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKNdIe1/9aPerTqPupof9a411D48XR/IrX3Uu/hR39RHXYuAJEjZ/zQuIy5zAA)

```apl
{⍵,⊃⍭1+×/⍵}⍣⎕⊢⎕
```

**Explanation**

```apl
{⍵,⊃⍭1+×/⍵}⍣⎕⊢⎕

             ⊢⎕  First get the first prime of the sequence S from input.
{         }⍣⎕    Then we repeat the code another input number of times.
     1+×/⍵       We take the product of S and add 1.
    ⍭            Get the prime factors of product(S)+1.
   ⊃             Get the first element, the smallest prime factor of prod(S)+1.
 ⍵,              And append it to S.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 45 bytes

```
(p,n)->s=p;for(i=2,n,s*=p=divisors(s+1)[2]);p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcoxCsMwDEbhq/x0slp5iKGUkioXMR4CwUWLI6zSqXd3k@XBg8/WrvFto0JGMG4UFxeb696DSuLGfhWTTb/qe/fgt4lyKjTbyKdpEEyMJ8O6tk/IxmgFF8TlSA3nEtEPhldEToz7oR@ljD8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
é|G╝╓c£¼_
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=827c47bcd6639cac5f&i=2+7%0A5+7%0A97+6&a=1&m=2)

Takes `p0` and (zero-indexed) `n` for input.  Produces `pn`.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>54</s> 53 bytes

```c
p;f(x,n){for(p=x;--n;p*=x)for(x=1;~p%++x;);return x;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCoMwEEXXeopBsCRNssiqyDQ36UZiI0I7HaLSgNijN01dfXj897wZvc@ZMYikSW7hFQW7hMYQ8tkl@QfJWfxwq1RCifG@rJEg4Z6f/URCbnU10QJsNRDW1ex7CqJph0bDia0sqDRAEDiwCARX6MooJYFjEY8vtMONikAagjhKsoh77i5fHx79OGfz/gE)

*-1 byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)*

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>33</s> 32 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to nwellnhof*

```perl6
{$_,{1+(2...-+^[*](@_)%%*)}...*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1olXqfaUFvDSE9PT1c7LlorVsMhXlNVVUuzFiiiVfu/OLFSIU3DSDM6zjzWmgvCMwXyLOA8S3Mg1zLW@j8A)

Anonymous code block that takes a number and returns a lazy list.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                              }  # Anonymous codeblock
                           ...*   # That returns an infinite list
 $_,                              # Starting with the input
    {                     }       # Where each element is
     1+(2...             )          # The first number above 2
                      %%*           # That cleanly divides
               [*](@_)                # The product of all numbers so far
            -+^                       # Plus one
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 49 bytes

```hs
g 1
g a b=b:g(a*b)([c|c<-[2..],1>mod(a*b+1)c]!!0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfpmCrEPM/XcGQK10hUSHJNskqXSNRK0lTIzq5JtlGN9pITy9Wx9AuNz8FJKxtqJkcq6hooPk/NzEzD6i1oCgzr0RBRaEkMTtVwVxBI03BSPP/v@S0nMT04v@6yQUFAA)

Returns the infinite sequence as a lazy list.

#### Explanation:

```hs
g 1                                            -- Initialise the product as 1
g a b=                                         -- Given the product and the current number
       b:                                      -- Return the current number, followed by
         g                                     -- Recursively calliong the function with
          (a*b)                                -- The new product
               (                             ) -- And get the next number as
                [c|c<-[2..],             ]!!0  -- The first number above 2
                            1>mod       c      -- That cleanly divides
                                 (a*b+1)       -- The product plus one
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
!¡ö←p→Π;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9odXNr//8hwqHDtuKGkHDihpLOoDv///85N/84)

For input `m`,`n` outputs the `n`-th term in the sequence starting with `m`.

Drop the initial `!` (for 7 bytes) to output the entire infinite sequence ([this link](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9odXNr/@KGkTEw4oKB/8Khw7bihpBw4oaSzqA7////OTc) selects the first 10 elements from the infinite list).
If both input & output are flexible enough (input: list of just the first term, output: infinite sequence) we could get down to [6 bytes](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9odXNr/@KGkTEw4oKB/8Khw7bihpBw4oaSzqD///9bOTdd).